# How to get notified when a method from different JVM is executed and get handle to arguments

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, javaagents, java-assist

Is there a way to get notified when a method from a Different JVM is called.

Dev Env: JDK8, Windows 10 (later on cloud for deployment).

I have couple of Java applications running, One in App Server and another is standalone batch process.

Whenever a core java class method is called on either of these JVM's e.g. PrintStream.print, I need to get handle to input string and log it somewhere else.

I tried with 
1. Java bytecode manipulation libraries e.g. Javassist, to transform byte code using Instrumentation, but it allows to have handle and manipulate User Defined classes / Third party library classes only - not java.*, sun.* etc... (**even if we do it somehow, it says - it violates JRE binary licence - Official Javadoc  says this process of instrumenting the rt.jar class violates the JRE binary code license - so this may not be the go ahead approach.
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html** )

2. Reflections - Can be used when you are on the same JVM, not sure if it works on different JVM.

   Appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Java agents are capable of retransformation which would allow you to install hooks into target classes even if they are loaded. Have a look into Byte Byddy's AgentBuilder for example.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter Thank You, I will have a look.  If Byte Buddy allows to transform java.* class, does it not violate the JRE binary code license.         Is there any other way to get method execution notification, from another JVM, apart from having a java agent.

Comment: When you only want to process what it prints, why don’t you connect the process via a pipe?

Comment: @Holger Thank You. If we mean tcp/rmi.socket connection, that is not the preferred option by partner applications. Constraint I have is - no code change at partner application, and no opening of ports.                       Appreciate your help and suggestion.

Comment: I didn’t mean changes to the application. When the application prints to its stdout, you can redirect it to a pipe and read it from your application.

Comment: Thank you RafaelWinterhalter and @Holger . You inputs have helped towards solution.